# Bulk insert into table with one single query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose i have one table [tblemployee]

```
i have one department = 21
i have one status = 3
i have value = 1,2,3,4
i have member = 21,22,32,45
```

i want one single query which will insert 4 record like

21 3 1 21

21 3 2 22

21 3 3 32

21 3 4 45

which mean department and status will be same for all row 
 please help me

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO tblemployee(department, status, value, member)
VALUES(21, 3, 1, 21),(21, 3, 2, 22),(21, 3, 3, 32),(21, 3, 4, 45);
```

You can find more information for the INSERT syntax in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-insert.html) (look for *multirow*).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for your query

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ID, Name)
SELECT 123, 'Timmy'
UNION ALL
SELECT 124, 'Jonny'
UNION ALL
SELECT 125, 'Sally'
```

Comment: Way too complicated. A simple INSERT with multiple rows will do.