# MySQL Column wise Insert

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a calculation logic using MySQL tables. 
Data from two table is processed using a stored procedure and a set of values is generated.
These values are part of a column of output table.
I have to run different procedure to generate output for each column in output table

Now if I create insert query for each row it will have large number of inserts for each column. Can I insert a set of values into a table column in one go? assuming other columns can be NULL.

Comment: yes e.g. insert into tabA (name,roll) values ('aaa',12) ; and assuming that tabA has one more column school , school will have the value as NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO tableName(columnName)
VALUES ('baz'),('foo'),('bar'),('baz'),('baz'),('baz'),('baz');
```

etc as u like..

See this: [Bulk insert into table with one single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994319/bulk-insert-into-table-with-one-single-query)

Answer (score 0):

The insert can be done for one column rest can be *NULL* if remaining columns are nullable.

But next time for the remaining columns the Insert will not work for the existing rows. If You want to update the existing rows then you need to fire the update query.

Assuming `col1` and `col2` are nullable

If you want to insert in `col1` keeping `col2` null insert will work
If you want to insert in `col2` keeping `col1` null insert will work